# using OpenNETCF/ossvcs.dll to turn on wireless radio on WindowsCE

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce, opennetcf

Can anyone tell me how to turn on wireless radio on Windows CE programatically using c# please?
Ideally I want my app turning the wireless on when it opens up on my PDA. The reason I want to do this is because wireless is always turned off on cold boot.

I tried:

1. Editing registry and using RegFlushKey() to commit the changes. But
   the changes only take effect after a warmreboot. A cold reboot resets the registry key
2. Searched to see if StartUpCtl could do this for me. I couldn't find anything on that
3. Tried to use ossvcs.dll. It wouldn't even let me add the dll to my project (if anyone has one that works please could you give me a copy)
4. Using OpenNETCF to see if wireless status can be changed from there. But there isn't much help out there.

Can anyone advise me please